# how to catch two illegalexeption in java

Tags: java

I have this code for school homework the problem when I run the code it only catches the first exception even though both are false.
the question is how can I catch two exceptions.

```java
public class Info {
    private String name;
    private int points;

    public Info(String n, int p) {
        setName(n);
        setPoints(p);
    }

    private void setName(String nameNew) {
        if (nameNew == null || nameNew.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("name should not be empty");

        }
        name = nameNew;
    }

    private void setPoints(int pointsNew) {
        if (pointsNew < 3 || pointsNew > 20) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("points should be between 3 and 20");
        }
        points = pointsNew;
    }
    public String f(){
        return (name + " "+ points);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Info student = new Info("", 60);
            System.out.println(student.f());
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException exc ) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't; execution of the `try` block does not continue after an exception is caught.

Comment: How should it come to the second check in `setPoints()` when the exception in `setName()` stops the execution of the `Info` constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. If an exception is thrown the normal flow of the code will be interrupted and thus the second exception will never be thrown. Instead you'd have to do both checks and throw a "combined" exception at the end.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
List<String> errors = new LinkedList<>();

//check the name
if (nameNew == null || nameNew.trim().isEmpty()) {
    errors.add("name should not be empty");
}

//check the points
if (pointsNew < 3 || pointsNew > 20) {
    errors.add("points should be between 3 and 20");
}

//if there are errors, throw an exception
if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
  //for simplicity we'll use IllegalArgumentException and concat the messages with a newline 
  //in a realworld application it would probably be best to use a custom exception and keep the list of errors
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.join("\n", errors));
}
```

Comment: thanks very much but i dont know how to combine the list to the code because it gives error on the nameNew and pointsNew.

Comment: @juliettebernard Well, you should be able to provide a new method with the corresponding parameters and call it or put that code directly into your constuctor (in which case you'd need to adapt the parameter names).

Comment: Yes i tried but it did not work i guess im doing something wrong because im new in java but thanks very much thomas.

Comment: @juliettebernard just create a new method, e.g. `checkInput(String nameNew, int pointsNew)` with the body as above and call it in your constructor, i.e. `checkInput(n, p);` - before calling the setters (which don't need to do the checks again if they stay `private`)

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown, processing will jump to wherever that exception is caught.

Because the try block is around your *call* to Info(), once Info() throws an exception (the first time, in it's call to setName()), you're going to move into the catch block in your main() function and be out of the Info() function entirely, so Info() will never reach its second line where it would have called setPoints().

If you want to catch both of them, you would need to ensure that Info remains active and resumes processing, which means that's where you want the exceptions to be handled.

```
public Info(String n, int p) {
    try {
        setName(n);
    catch (IllegalArgumentException exc ) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        setPoints(p);
    catch (IllegalArgumentException exc ) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In this version, Info() is handling the exception from its call to setName(), and then ***after*** that catch moving on to calling setPoints(), which may also have an exception that Info() will also handle.

With this scenario, Info() itself will never throw an IllegalArgumentException, since it's already handled the ones that can occur during it, so you wouldn't need the try/catch for in in your main() function.

EDIT:
Ok, I missed the class name and the fact that this is in the constructor.  What I said initially would be valid if Info() was a regular function being called.  But with a constructor, you may want an Exception to tell you it wasn't able to initialize correctly.

But the main point still applies.  If you want to see both errors, you need to ensure that the constructor calls both setter functions.  You could add tracking of the fact that there was at least one error, and re-throw the exception so that your main sees that the constructor failed:

```
public Info(String n, int p) {
    boolean failure = false;
    try {
        setName(n);
    catch (IllegalArgumentException exc ) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        failure = true;
    }

    try {
        setPoints(p);
    catch (IllegalArgumentException exc ) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        failure = true;
    }

    if (failure) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid parameters");
    }
}
```